# Jacobian of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I understand from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Matrix-by-scalar) that if two Matrices $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$ and ${N \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times t}}$ whose elements are real functions over $\mathbb{R}^n$; i.e.,

$N_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

and

$M_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

for all $i,j$ are given, then the Jacobian of their product $MN$ is (**SEE EDIT AT THE BOTTOM)**:

$$M\frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{\textbf{x}}}+\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{\textbf{x}}}N\tag{1}$$

However, I have been thus far unable to demonstrate that formula. To keep notations simple, I will write my attempt in the following particular case (the solution will be similar in higher dimensions I think):

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22}  
\end{pmatrix}
\textbf{v}
$$
where $\textbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}^2$, and $a_{ij} : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for all $i,j$. We seek to compute the Jacobian 
$$
\frac{\partial(A\textbf{v})}{\partial(\textbf{x})}\tag{2}
$$

Let $A_i$ denote row $i$, and write

$$A\textbf{v}=\begin{pmatrix}A_1\textbf{v}\\A_2\textbf{v} \end{pmatrix}$$

Equation (2) becomes
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\partial(A_1\textbf{v})}{\partial(\textbf{x}_1)} && \frac{\partial(A_1\textbf{v})}{\partial(\textbf{x}_2)} \\
\frac{\partial(A_2\textbf{v})}{\partial(\textbf{x}_1)}&& \frac{\partial(A_2\textbf{v})}{\partial(\textbf{x}_2)}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial(A_1\textbf{v})}{\textbf{x}}\\
\frac{\partial(A_2\textbf{v})}{\textbf{x}}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{3}
$$
and it is easy to demonstrate that
$$
\frac{\partial(A_iv)}{\partial(\textbf{x})}=A_i\frac{\partial(v)}{\partial(\textbf{x})}+v^T\frac{\partial(A_i^T)}{\partial(\textbf{x})}.
$$
Substituting in (3) results in

$$
A\frac{\partial{\textbf{v}}}{\partial{x}}+
\begin{pmatrix}
\textbf{v}^T\frac{\partial{A_1^T}}{\partial{\textbf{x}}}\\
\textbf{v}^T\frac{\partial{A_2^T}}{\partial{\textbf{x}}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

which differs from (1). What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Turns out $\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{x}}N$ in (1) is not a usual matrix product, but a component-wise one (see the answer provided by @muaddib)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think looking at the derivative of the application of a matrix on a vector isn't the right route to deriving this expression.  So I'm not saying the above is wrong, but I will give you another derivation.

Since you mentioned the wiki article, I will assume we already know that if $A, B$ are matrices with coefficients that are functions $A_{ij},B_{ij} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ then
$$\frac{d}{dx}(AB) = (\frac{d}{dx}A)B + A (\frac{d}{dx}B)$$

Now suppose $C$ is a matrix with whose coefficients are functions $C_{ij} = \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$.  Then I'll define the Jacobian $\frac{\partial}{\partial\textbf{x}}$ of $C$ by
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\textbf{x}} C = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} C\right) e_i$$
where $e_i$ is the $i$th standard base component of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  So $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \textbf{x}}$ is a vector whose components are matrices.  Now

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{x}}(AB) &= &\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} AB \right) e_i \\
   &= &\sum_{i=1}^n \left((\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}A)B + A (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}B) \right) e_i \\
   &= &\sum_{i=1}^n \left((\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}A)B \right)e_i+ \sum_{i=1}^nA \left((\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}B) \right) e_i \\   
   &= & (\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{x}}A)B + A (\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{x}}B) \\   
\end{eqnarray*}

Note that in the final expression, the products of a jacobian of a matrix (a vector of matrices) and another matrix is performed component-wise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! However, I'm not sure i understand your definition of $\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{\textbf{x}}}$. The vector $\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{x_i}}$ is of size $n\times 1$, and so is $e_i$. Therefore it seems to me that their product as it is doesn't make much sense...

Comment: further more, I think i misunderstood the wikipedia page, actually the formula I was trying to demonstrate seems to hold only when each element is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Ash If $C$ is an $m$ by $p$ matrix then $\frac{\partial C}{\partial x_i}$ is an $m$ by $p$ matrix.  It is one of the $n$ components of the jacobian (which is a vector of matrices).

Comment: Then shouldn't $e_i$ also be $p$ by $1$?

Comment: No, I am not multiplying $\frac{\partial C}{\partial x_i}$ by $e_i$ in the sense of matrix multiplication.  It's the same way you denote a standard vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$ as $v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i e_i$.  There $v_i$ is a number and $e_i$ is a vector.  Here, $v_i$ is a matrix.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad. I have to concede, this is a nice notation.  I realize now that the last expression of my question is an ugly version of the last expression of your post (it can be rearranged to look the same in any dimensions, btw I just used matrix on vector because my notations were cumbersome for higher dimensions). So actually I had misunderstood the fromula from wikipedia, I will edit the question, thanks.

Comment: My pleasure.  And yes, for me at least, half of the issues with these "tensors" is how to notate them.  It just gets harder and harder as there are more "indexes".